# Using Powermock with TestNG using EasyMock. throws exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, easymock, powermock

I am trying to write a TestNg test using Powermock to mock a static function call.
My test code is :

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify;

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


@PrepareForTest(TestStringProvider.class)
public class TryPowerMock {

    public void test() {
        String string = TestStringProvider.getString();
        Assert.assertEquals(string, "testString");
    }

    @Test
    public void tryPowerMock() {
        mockStatic(TestStringProvider.class);        
        expect(TestStringProvider.getString()).andReturn("testString");
        replay(TestStringProvider.class);
        test();
        verify(TestStringProvider.class);
    }

}
```

Class with static function:

```
public class TestStringProvider {
    public static String getString(){
        return "WHY AM I CALLED, I AM SUPPOSED TO BE MOCKED";
    }

}
```

Running this test gives me following exception,

```
FAILED: tryPowerMock
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:520)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:498)
    at com.archit.learn.powermock.TryPowerMock.tryPowerMock(TryPowerMock.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explored some more and found the solution myself.

I had to extend my unit test from class PowerMockTestCase